# Como persistir o valor retornado por um método?

Tags: java, hibernate

Em uma classe que possui uma coleção, preciso persistir a contagem de elementos da coleção que sigam determinada condição.

Assim sendo, preciso salvar o resultado de um método que checa todos os elementos desta coleção. Exemplo:

```
class Group
{
   private List<Person> persons;

   @Column
   public getMarriedPersons()
   {
       int cont = 0;
       for(Person p : getPersons())
       {
           if(p.isMarried()){cont++;}
       }
       return cont;
   }
}
```

Eu poderia criar um propriedade e carregar o valor dela antes de salvar, porém não seria o ideal, pois caso seja persistida por outra classe o programador poderia esquecer de carregar o valor da mesma.

Contudo teria como persistir o retorno desse método, ou eu poderia apenas implementá-lo no método GET da propriedade?

Porém o Hibernate trabalha com o valor da propriedade e não do campo, teria como mudar isto para esta situação?

Answer (score 2):

Honestamente não vejo ganho nenhum com essa abordagem, mas já que você quer uma saída para isso, utilize um método anotado com PrePersist.

```
@Entity
public class Entitidade() {
    private List<Pessoa> pessoaList;
    private Integer total;

    @PrePersist @PreUpdate
    public void prePersist() {
        // aqui vc faz o calculo
    }
}
```

Antes de inserir ou atualizar esse método será chamado e você terá o valor calculado.